# Get Value of index of array according to desire term in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here is the output of my array

[image]

i want to search which value is on which index becuse every time indexes are changed in array 
here is second screen shot

[image]

how i check for example i want to search value male is placed on which index
and also want to check value placed or not mean value is there or not present there

```
public function ajax(){
    $array      = $_POST['checkbox'];

    $searchTerm = "male";

if (false !== ($pos = $this->array_search2d_by_field($searchTerm, $array))) {
echo $searchTerm . " found at index " . $pos;
} else {
echo "Could not find " . $searchTerm;
}


}
function array_search2d_by_field($needle, $haystack) {
foreach ($haystack as $index => $innerArray) {
    if (isset($innerArray) && $innerArray === $needle) {
        return $index;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can follow this to get the array index of a value http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: Unclear what you asking ...............

Comment: Adding some example with your expected output is quite helpful

Comment: @MuhammadUsman remove you asnwer below

Comment: i got my answer man that y litle problem can u slove dat plz

Comment: @MuhammadUsman tell me with what you need to search and what are the conditions as well

Comment: @Abdulla i want pass values to query how i pass that if value is empty my query must run with with 2 parameters kindly chat with me

Comment: function filterartion(){
   $query  = $this->db->query("Select * from members where (gender = 'male ' OR gender = 'female') AND (`status` = '1' OR `status` = '0') AND
       blood_group = 'b+' OR blood_group ='a+' ");
   return $query->result_array();
  }
       blood_group = '".$array."' ");
   return $query->result_array();
  }

Comment: @Abdulla here is my query i want to run the query if any parameter is empty it also run on 2 parameters

Comment: @Abdulla how i search the value which are coming on indexes of array how i cancate with query mean pass to query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102356/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-abdulla).

Comment: What unpragmatically way of distributing crutial data such is blood type. "becuse every time indexes are changed in array" <- This must NOT happen. Someone could die because not having bullet proof architecture of application that is responsible for input and output data. :fear:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

This is an flexible search based on your selected check-box values

```
function filterartion($array){

    $array = array(
        '0' => 'av', 
        '1' => 'nav', 
        '2' => 'male', 
        '3' => 'female', 
        '4' => 'A+', 
        '5' => 'A-', 
    );

    // Gender
    if(in_array("male", $array))
    {
        $gender[] =  'male';
    }
    if(in_array("female", $array))
    {
        $gender[] = 'female';
    }

    // Status
    if(in_array("av", $array))
    {
        $status[] =  '1';
    }
    if(in_array("nav", $array))
    {
        $status[] = '0';
    }

    // Group
    if(in_array("A+", $array))
    {
        $group[] =  'A+';
    }
    if(in_array("A-", $array))
    {
        $group[] = 'A-';
    }

    $this->db->slect("*");
    $this->db->from("members");
    $this->db->where_in('gender', $gender);
    $this->db->where_in('status', $status);
    $this->db->where_in('blood_group', $group);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    // return $result;
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: (Y) thanx for passion of helping

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Happy to help :)

Comment: This is good example

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function:

> **Example #1 array_search() example**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
> $key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
> $key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
> ?>
> ```

And the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

> **Example #1 in_array() example**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
> if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
>     echo "Got Irix";
> }
> if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
>     echo "Got mac";
> }
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ajax(){
    $array      = $_POST['checkbox'];

    $searchTerm = "male";

if (false !== ($pos = $this->array_search2d_by_field($searchTerm, $array))) {
echo $searchTerm . " found at index " . $pos;
} else {
echo "Could not find " . $searchTerm;
}


}
function array_search2d_by_field($needle, $haystack) {
foreach ($haystack as $index => $innerArray) {
    if (isset($innerArray) && $innerArray === $needle) {
        return $index;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```